# Помогите с preg_replace

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Входящие данные:

```
<p class="title">Title one</p>
<p class="title">Title two</p>
<p class="title">Title three</p>
```

Регулярка:

```
/<p.*?class=["']*title["']*.*?>.*?<\/p.*?>/si
```

Заменяю на: (preg_replace)

```
<p class="my">My text on two</p>
```

Всё отлично, получается, но заменяются все совпадения:

```
<p class="my">My text on two</p>
<p class="my">My text on two</p>
<p class="my">My text on two</p>
```

А мне нужно заменить только N-ое совпадение, скажем, только второе, чтобы получилось:

```
<p class="title">Title one</p>
<p class="my">My text on two</p>
<p class="title">Title three</p>
```

Подскажите куда копать....
Если что вот PHP фиддл: http://ideone.com/GCrNcK

Comment: Правьте регулярку указывая больше данных для поиска совпадений. Если список во входящих данных будет строится по принципу title+number
то добавлйте в условие number

Comment: Именно что входящие данные абсолютно одинаковые :( есть какой то способ `preg_replace($preg, $replace, $data, $limit, $counter);` вот связано с $limit и $counter но не могу никак понять, может кто разжуёт...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть вариант пользовать [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$repl_counter = 0;

echo preg_replace_callback($reg, function($match) use (&$repl_counter, $repl)
    {
    $res = $match[0];   // default
    if ($repl_counter == 1) // second occurrence
        $res = $repl;
    $repl_counter++;
    return $res;
    }, $data);
```

http://ideone.com/qt1LxG

Comment: Ага да!!! Вот за это огромнейшее спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно несколько действий

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match);
for($i=0; $i < count($match); $i++) {
    if ($i == 2) {
        preg_replace($replace_pattern, $str, $text);
    }
}
```